# How to use dynamic or relative path in SPList object?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, visual-web-part, splist

I am using the following code to read a picture library:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.GetList("http://win-12/sites/mysite/ImageLibrary")
```

Problem is, in above code "win-12" is my machine name and if I move this web part to some other server, I don't think it will work!?

So I want to know how to use dynamic or relative path instead of hard coded one?

Or before moving this web part to new server, I will have to change its URL then recompile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of using absolute URL. You can pass server-relative URL of the list in *SPWeb.GetList()*.

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.GetList("/sites/mysite/ImageLibrary")
```

Comment: Ok I just realized one thing. On my development machine, site's name is "mysite" as you can see in URL above. What if on production, site's name is something else? Then my webpart won't work. How to make it work then?

Comment: Have the list in current web and use SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["<your-list-name>"]; Although this is less preferred way in case your web is having a lot of lists.

Comment: This brings me to another problem. My current list is created in "parent" site. I have two variations "English" and "Arabic". So when I give list name in above code, it gives error that "list not found" because "English" is the default variation that opens while list is created in "parent" hence it cannot access it. If I define my list in "English" then "Arabic" site won't be able to access it.